# Magento1 How to set template for a widget?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, widget

I have created a widget and I don't know how to set the phtml template for the widget.

Comment: Can you please explain your question?

Comment: I need to set the template for the widget. Which part you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your widget.xml, your widget looks like:

```
<widget_name type="module_name/new_widget" translate="name description" module="module_name">
```

So your block class is:

**app/code/local/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/New/Widget.php**

```
class VendorName_ModuleName_Block_New_Widget
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    /**
     * Internal constructor
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('module_name/template.phtml');
    }
}
```

***You can check app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/widget.xml as an example.***

Comment: /**
     * Internal constructor
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('fsm/advertisingbanner/index.phtml');
    }
This is the location of index.phtml 
Fsm_AdvertisingBanner/app/design/frontend/base/default/fsm/advertisingbanner/index.phtml

Comment: but still nothing

Comment: Change like: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/fsm/advertisingbanner/index.phtml